# java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid ID for region-based ZoneId, invalid format: Java

Tags: java, time, timezone

I want to get by city UTC and GMT time *without underscore*. Firstly, I'm writting to get zone ids:

```
 List<String> utc = new ArrayList<>(ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds());
 List<String> gmt = new ArrayList<>(ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds());
```

But I have underscore and I'm changing to empty space:

```
  List<String> newList_utc = new ArrayList<>();
  List<String> newList_gmt = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String anUtc : utc) {
        if (anUtc.contains("_")) {
            newList_utc.add(anUtc.replace("_", " "));
        } else {
            newList_utc.add(anUtc);
        }
    }

    for (String aGmt : gmt) {
        if (aGmt.contains("_")) {
            newList_gmt.add(aGmt.replace("_", " "));
        } else {
            newList_gmt.add(aGmt);
        }
    }
```

After splitting I have specific city, e.g. - `El Salvador`. Before splitting and changing was `America/El_Salvador` as format.

And I'm using the following code to output time zones with offset:

```
newList_utc.stream().filter(it -> it.contains("El Salvador")).collect(Collectors.toList());
newList_utc.stream().filter(it -> it.contains("America/El Salvador")).map(Class::getOffset).collect(Collectors.toList());

...
...

private static String getOffset(String zone) {
       ZonedDateTime zdt = LDT.atZone(ZoneId.of(zone));
       return zdt.getOffset().getId().replace("Z", "+00:00");
}
```

Finally, I get the error:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid ID for region-based ZoneId, invalid format: America/El Salvador
    at java.time.ZoneRegion.checkName(ZoneRegion.java:151)
    at java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:116)
    at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)
    at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:359)
    at project.Bot.getOffset(Bot.java:5822)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at project.Bot.getOutputZone(Bot.java:6070)
    at project.Bot.getTimeZone(Bot.java:6041)
    at project.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:399)
```

During debugging, it happens because of `getOffset()`method on this line `ZonedDateTime zdt = LDT.atZone(ZoneId.of(zone));` where I set `America/El Salvador`. If I write `America/El_Salvador` then I don't have this issue.

But why I can't use empty space instead of underscore?

Comment: The ZoneID is defined by [an external database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). If it is defined with an underscore, it expects an underscore.

Comment: @Compass, oh, it makes sense. Thank you. I thought if I change it, I get another result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Zone IDs are actually not defined by Java standard, but outside of Java in a data set known as the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Data_structure) which is a public domain time zone standard, designed for interoperability between applications and programming languages.

The rules behind time zone names are:

> The time zones have unique names in the form "Area/Location", e.g. "America/New_York". A choice was also made to use English names or equivalents, and to omit punctuation and common suffixes. **The underscore character is used in place of spaces.** Hyphens are used where they appear in the name of a location. The Area and Location names have a maximum length of 14 characters.

So, the underscore is required based on the format, so using time zones with spaces instead of underscores will not work, not because Java doesn't support it, but because there is no matching tz entry for it.

If you want to convert from a tz to a clean display, you can replace the underscores with a space, and vice versa to convert a clean display back into a timezone id.

[Ref: relatively current tz codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: yes, to solve the issue, I replaced empty space to underscore before using getOffset() method.